# Elasticsearch not working with sugarcrm 7.5.0.1

Tags: elasticsearch, sugarcrm

I have upgraded a SugarCRM 7.2.2.0 to 7.5.0.1.
Then I have updated java to v7 and elasticsearch to v1.3.1

After starting elasticsearch, and launching indexing, the global search keep not giving any results.

Here is the output of elasticsearch when it is launched :

```
/usr/local/bin/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
[2014-12-17 09:11:37,057][INFO ][node                     ] [Wild Child] version[1.3.1], pid[19801], build[2de6dc5/2014-07-28T14:45:15Z]
[2014-12-17 09:11:37,059][INFO ][node                     ] [Wild Child] initializing...
[2014-12-17 09:11:37,066][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Wild Child] loaded [], sites []
[2014-12-17 09:11:39,896][WARN ][common.network           ] failed to resolve local host, fallback to loopback
java.net.UnknownHostException: sm4.localdomain: sm4.localdomain: Name or service not known
  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkUtils.<clinit>(NetworkUtils.java:54)
  at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.<init>(NettyTransport.java:204)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sm4.localdomain: Name or service not known
  at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
  at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
... 62 more
[2014-12-17 09:11:40,779][INFO ][node                     ] [Wild Child] initialized
[2014-12-17 09:11:40,780][INFO ][node                     ] [Wild Child] starting ...
[2014-12-17 09:11:41,002][INFO ][transport                ] [Wild Child] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/92.39.241.87:9300]}
[2014-12-17 09:11:41,046][INFO ][discovery                ] [Wild Child] elasticsearch/OeRmy39vTz2WTcnjSXoHHA
[2014-12-17 09:11:44,095][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Wild Child] new_master [Wild Child][OeRmy39vTz2WTcnjSXoHHA][localhost][inet[/92.39.241.87:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-12-17 09:11:44,133][INFO ][http                     ] [Wild Child] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/92.39.241.87:9200]}
[2014-12-17 09:11:44,134][INFO ][node                     ] [Wild Child] started
[2014-12-17 09:11:45,039][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Wild Child] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
```

Though the localhost:9200 is accessible.

Then when I schedule system index on Sugar, nothing seems to happen in any elasticsearch log.

Did anyone already have this problem ?

Any help will be much appreciated !

Thank you

Cheers, Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved my issue.
Indeed, upgrading java is necessary.

For my part, I had to add the line in the crontab to call `cron.php` to make elasticsearch work with Sugarcrm.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you have this resolved yet.  I recently did the same upgrade, and had to update my java version to 1.7, and additionally, had to ensure that my locations for logs and data were writable (elasticsearch user and elasticsearch group).